# Sonar Configure

Tags: java, sonarqube

I installed Sonar Plugin on my eclipse, (i ran the server .../StartSonar.bat) and when I do test connection on LocalHost:9000 its okay (Connection Sucessfull). Now What should I do to associate my projects with sonar? I'm kind lost. I'm rookie.

Answer (score 3):

If your projects are built with maven then all you need to do is run `mvn sonar:sonar` on your project root folder (where your `pom.xml` is located) and the report will get pushed to your sonar instance.

And also you need to have the sonar profile set up in your settings.xml. Example below:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- EXAMPLE FOR MYSQL -->
                <sonar.jdbc.url>
                  jdbc:mysql://localhost:9000/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
                </sonar.jdbc.url>
                <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
                <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
                <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>

                <!-- SERVER ON A REMOTE HOST -->
                <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
     </profile>
```

Read more [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Maven).

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz - thanks for the edit .. I accidentally typed `maven` instead of `mvn`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To use the plugin in Eclipse SonarQube you must have a sonarQube instance (server) installed, documentation on how to do can be found at the following link http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade.

Once you have performed an initial analysis of your code, either as maven says Tomasz or sonar-runner, (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) you can, with sonarqube plugin for Eclipse, set a reference to the server in the General preferences Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> SonarQube -> Servers and project level should "link" or refer to said first analysis located in your server.

Once you do this, every time you make an analysis of your code with SonarQube from Eclipse, it will connect to the server, the existing evidences will be brought and will do an incremental analysis of your code with respect to information collected on the remote analysis.